# Cant publish via PUBNUB. Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, pubnub

Make it Using javascript API. On their site works fine, but locally cant send cross-domain request. Where is the problem?

request is XMLHttpRequest cannot load

> http://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/KEY//0/broadcast/0/%224444444444444%22.

Origin localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: BTW, Subscribing to same channel works fine!And there is the same cross-domain get-request

Comment: Hi SAHbKA!  Looking at your post now and will give you an update shortly.

Comment: The solution is to remove the origin="" attribute from the PubNub settings.  I am writing for you more details below.

Comment: sorry, where should I remove this setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Using PubNub Everywhere! Even localhost and file:///

Using PubNub on *localhost* is super easy!  You can even use PubNub on *file:///* as well.

NOTE: [always use a fixed versioned CDN in production](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk), but pubnub-dev.js cdn is always the latest version, unminified.

```
<script src=https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-dev.js></script>
<script>(function(){

    var pubnub = PUBNUB({
        // use your own pub/sub keys - demo keys are throttled
        publish_key   : 'demo',
        subscribe_key : 'demo',
        origin        : 'pubsub.pubnub.com',
        ssl           : true
    });

    pubnub.subscribe({
        channel  : 'my_channel',
        connect  : function() { /* ... CONNECTION SUCCESS ... */ },
        callback : function(message) {
            alert(message);
        }
    });

})();</script>
```

Remember to keep the *origin* set to **pubsub.pubnub.com** for all settings.

Comment: thanks for advice, but it didnt help
my erroris
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/pub-a118*************//0/broadcast/0/%7B%22sender%22%3A%22SAnya11%20%20Nikulin%22%2C%22message%22%3A%221111%22%7D. Origin http://127.0.0.1:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[0, "Disconnected"]

Comment: Probably it is because of 3.1 version. Tried 3.3. And now I cant Init
var pubnub = PUBNUB({
               publish_key   : 'demo',
               subscribe_key : 'demo',
               origin        : 'pubsub.pubnub.com',
               ssl           : true
           }); 
TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: It is reeeaaally very strange, but everything works fine on other dev pc. Also, works fine in Incognito page... My fault, thanks for help

Comment: @Stephen Blum this was a very simple solution. specially if you are using PubNub through browser for any purpose. thank you.